# Unable to properly establish One to Many Unidirectional Mapping in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

Recently I have been practicing ER mapping between two entities and went forward to try unidirectional One-To-Many Mapping. I am using SpringBoot 2 with Spring-Data-JPA and H2 database.

There are two Entities under model package : `University` and `Student`
In this One-to-many relation I m aiming at implementing a relation where multiple students can be related to one University.

**University.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "univ")
public class University {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer Id ;
    private String Name ;
    @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    private List <Student> std =  new ArrayList<>() ;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public List<Student> getStd() {
        return std;
    }

    public void setStd(List<Student> std) {
        this.std = std;
    }

    public University(String name, List<Student> std) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.std = std;
    }
}
```

**Student.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer rollno ;
    private String Name ;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "univ")
    private University univ ;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public University getUniv() {
        return univ;
    }

    public void setUniv(University univ) {
        this.univ = univ;
    }

    public Student(String name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Under Repository package I have created two interfaces for repository of each Entity extended using CrudRepository Interface.
Lastly this is main method under **Application.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(H2SetupApplication.class, args);
        StdRepository stdRepository = context.getBean(StdRepository.class );
        UnivRepository univRepository = context.getBean(UnivRepository.class);

        Student std1 = new Student("John" ) ;
        Student std2 = new Student("Sam" ) ;

        List <Student> students = Arrays.asList(std1, std2) ;

        University university = new University("USCIT", students) ;
        univRepository.save(university) ;


    }
```

The problem I am currently facing is shown in the screenshot below 
[image] 
The **UNIV** column in **STUDENT** table is null instead of expected value to be **1**

Another unknown behaviour I noticed was if I move `@JoinColumn(name = "univ")` from *Student.java* to *University.java* class then the tables are formed as shown below :
[image]

In this scenario two new doubts arise in my mind :

1. Where is the third table, since it's supposed to be still a
   unidirectional mapping as I haven't used `mappedBy()`
2. Why is there a column named UNIV_ID in Student table and that too
   with null values

Comment: Just for your reference: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa

Comment: @dkb if you were able to get my mistake, can you point me out where did I go wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "univ")
public class University {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer Id ;
    private String Name ;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "university",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List <Student> std =  new ArrayList<>() ;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public List<Student> getStd() {
        return std;
    }

    public void setStd(List<Student> std) {
        this.std = std;
    }

    public University(String name, List<Student> std) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.std = std;
    }
}

After doing this, 
delete the university and students table and rerun the project
```